# How to test for uniformity

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I simulate times in the range `0` to T according to a Poisson process.  The inter-event times are exponential and we know that the distribution of the times should be uniform in the range `0` to `T`.

```
def poisson_simul(rate, T):
    time = random.expovariate(rate)
    times = [0]
    while (times[-1] < T):
        times.append(time+times[-1])
        time = random.expovariate(rate)
    return times[1:]
```

I would simply like to run one of the tests for uniformity, for example the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. I can't work out how to do this in scipy however. If I do

```
import random
from scipy.stats import kstest
times = poisson_simul(1, 100)
print kstest(times, "uniform")
```

it is not right . It gives me

```
(1.0, 0.0)
```

I just want to test the hypothesis that the points are uniformly chosen from the range `0` to `T`. How do you do this in scipy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to provide the parameters of the uniform distribution to let `kstest()` know that it is a uniform distribution from 0 to 100. If you just specify `'uniform'`, you get the default bounds of 0 to 1, which the data obviously does not fit. The clearest way to do this is to specify the CDF function directly instead of using the strings:

```
[~]
|11> from scipy import stats

[~]
|12> times = poisson_simul(1.0, 100.0)

[~]
|13> stats.kstest(times, stats.uniform(loc=0.0, scale=100.0).cdf)
(0.047464592615975507, 0.98954417186125665)
```

Comment: Thank you. You don't seem to have to specify how many points which is interesting.

Comment: It just looks at the input for that. Strictly speaking, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is testing whether the N data points that you gave it look enough like N data points drawn from the given distribution. It does not know that these data are times generated by a point process with a time-based cutoff rather than a number-based cutoff. If the distinction matters to you, you need a different statistical test.

Comment: Thank you. I have recently read that the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is not a great choice to test uniformity.  Do you happen to know of any more powerful tests that can be used in python?